# convert .pb to .tflite ,RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, toco

convert .pb model to tflite model 
run the bug:
RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b'e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.\r\n  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\toco\python\tensorflow_wrap_toco.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper\r\n    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(\'_tensorflow_wrap_toco\', [dirname(**file**)])\r\n  File "e:\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module\r\n    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)\r\nImportError: No module named \'_tensorflow_wrap_toco\'\r\n\r\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r\n\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "e:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main\r\n    "**main**", mod_spec)\r\n  File "e:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code\r\n    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File "E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\toco_from_protos.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in \r\n  File "e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\toco\python\toco_from_protos.py", line 22, in \r\n    from tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python import tensorflow_wrap_toco\r\n  File "e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\toco\python\tensorflow_wrap_toco.py", line 28, in \r\n    _tensorflow_wrap_toco = swig_import_helper()\r\n  File "e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\toco\python\tensorflow_wrap_toco.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper\r\n    import _tensorflow_wrap_toco\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'_tensorflow_wrap_toco\'\r\n'
None

Answer (score 0):

Check your graph. You might be using some unsupported operations: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/tf_ops_compatibility.md

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58583419/11517841

Using Colab to convert your .pb into .lite is much simpler!